# Better Compression with jpegoptim

Tags: image-optimization, jpegoptim

I'm trying to optimize my photos for google insight. I'm using jpegoptim for it.

I'm using

```
$jpegoptim --strip-all --max=60 myfile.jpg
```

but still google insight says that it is possible reduce file size +60%

Then I tried

```
$jpegoptim --strip-all --max=0 myfile.jpg
```

this time google insight says that every thing is perfect. But now quality is very poor.

Then, I have tried

```
jpeg tran "jpegtran myfile.jpg > newmyfile.jpg
```

but filesize is more than jpegoptim's.

So,what is the best way to compress image for google insight?

Here is the images :

```
http://webbayi.net/notoptimized.jpg
http://webbayi.net/optimized.jpg
http://webbayi.net/max0.jpeg
```

Comment: Well... why trust google's opinion? Decide yourself which setting is acceptable. If max=60 is wasting bits and max=0 is too bad, check the values within this range!

Comment: I'm wondering about google insight because it is important for seo.

Comment: Then try numbers inbetween this range. There is also mozjpeg, which might be a bit better at some costs (but jpegoptim/jpeg tran should be enough). If that's not working it will be hard to further optimize. You would need some image-processing steps like reducing dimensions, colors or blurring.

Comment: only --max=0 is accepted by google. --max=10 gives result as %10 possible to reduce.

Comment: Then show us the original image (and maybe the transforms with max=0, and max=10. It might be possible that color-reduction saves a lot. But it might also possible that google's algorithm is just failing.

Comment: I have edited my post, please check the photo links at the bottom of the page.

Comment: How is this a programming question?

Comment: Ok: the problem is not really about the usage of jpegoptim and co. but more about how to prepare & incorporate your images in your web-service. I'm sure googles service complaints because of the non-cropped nature of that image. >80% is white. As i'm not into that stuff i can't help here, but some short readings hint that this uncropped images are not really liked there.

Answer (score 0):

I use `nconvert` to resize and then `jpegoptim --force --max=70 --strip-icc --quiet`